# Google Assistant responding with "Sorry, I didn't get any response"

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I have a smart home action that supports multiple device categories including blinds, doors and windows. The only time this error message comes up is when I say "Close all the windows". The windows are individually addressable. Google Home responds fine if I say "Close all the blinds". On the backend, they're essentially the same and the only thing that's different is the device category. Is there something wrong with this particular device category? This is all in english.

Comment: Can you provide your sync response and the commands you're giving which are failing?

Comment: @NickFelker I replied as an answer since it was too long for a comment. Hope that's okay.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sync response:

```
{
"requestId": "5149816291025266974",
"payload": {
    "agentUserId": "XXXXHOME45",
    "devices": [
        {
            "id": "HOME-34002c000a47363339343638-11",
            "name": {
                "name": "Bedroom 1"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.DOOR",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-34002c000a47363339343638-12",
            "name": {
                "name": "Bedroom 2"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.DOOR",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-34002c000a47363339343638-13",
            "name": {
                "name": "Bathroom"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.DOOR",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-34002c000a47363339343638-14",
            "name": {
                "name": "Balcony"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.DOOR",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-3e0030000b47363339343638-19",
            "name": {
                "name": "Window 1"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.WINDOW",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ],
            "roomHint": "Living Room"
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-3e0030000b47363339343638-20",
            "name": {
                "name": "Window 2"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.WINDOW",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ],
            "roomHint": "Living Room"
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-3e0030000b47363339343638-21",
            "name": {
                "name": "Window 1"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.WINDOW",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ],
            "roomHint": "Master Bedroom"
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-3e0030000b47363339343638-22",
            "name": {
                "name": "Window 2"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.WINDOW",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ],
            "roomHint": "Master Bedroom"
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-330035000a47363339343638-17",
            "name": {
                "name": "Blind 1"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.BLINDS",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ],
            "roomHint": "Master Bedroom"
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-3c002b000747363339343638-23",
            "name": {
                "name": "Window 1"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.WINDOW",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ],
            "roomHint": "Second Bedroom"
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-3c002b000747363339343638-24",
            "name": {
                "name": "Window 2"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.WINDOW",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ],
            "roomHint": "Second Bedroom"
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-330035000a47363339343638-28",
            "name": {
                "name": "Blind 1"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.BLINDS",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ],
            "roomHint": "Second Bedroom"
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-330035000a47363339343638-18",
            "name": {
                "name": "Blind 2"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.BLINDS",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ],
            "roomHint": "Second Bedroom"
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-34002c000a47363339343638-15",
            "name": {
                "name": "Blind 1"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.BLINDS",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ],
            "roomHint": "Living Room"
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-34002c000a47363339343638-16",
            "name": {
                "name": "Blind 2"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.BLINDS",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ],
            "roomHint": "Living Room"
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-34002c000a47363339343638-10",
            "name": {
                "name": "Front Door"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.DOOR",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-340031000d47363330353437-133",
            "name": {
                "name": "Stove"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.OUTLET",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OnOff"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's a screenshot of me saying the commands. As you can see, the window command gets the "didnt get a response" message BUT all the windows do indeed close in real life. Also I can individually control the windows.
[image: Google Assistant]

EDIT:
Okay I changed my discovery from WINDOW to AWNING and that made it work. So it looks like there is something going on with the window device type? Again I'll attach the discovery response.

```
{
"requestId": "5149816291025266974",
"payload": {
    "agentUserId": "XXXXHOME45",
    "devices": [
        {
            "id": "HOME-34002c000a47363339343638-11",
            "name": {
                "name": "Bedroom 1"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.DOOR",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-34002c000a47363339343638-12",
            "name": {
                "name": "Bedroom 2"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.DOOR",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-34002c000a47363339343638-13",
            "name": {
                "name": "Bathroom"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.DOOR",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-34002c000a47363339343638-14",
            "name": {
                "name": "Balcony"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.DOOR",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-3e0030000b47363339343638-19",
            "name": {
                "name": "Window 1"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.AWNING",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ],
            "roomHint": "Living Room"
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-3e0030000b47363339343638-20",
            "name": {
                "name": "Window 2"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.AWNING",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ],
            "roomHint": "Living Room"
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-3e0030000b47363339343638-21",
            "name": {
                "name": "Window 1"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.AWNING",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ],
            "roomHint": "Master Bedroom"
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-3e0030000b47363339343638-22",
            "name": {
                "name": "Window 2"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.AWNING",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ],
            "roomHint": "Master Bedroom"
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-330035000a47363339343638-17",
            "name": {
                "name": "Blind 1"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.BLINDS",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ],
            "roomHint": "Master Bedroom"
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-3c002b000747363339343638-23",
            "name": {
                "name": "Window 1"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.AWNING",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ],
            "roomHint": "Second Bedroom"
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-3c002b000747363339343638-24",
            "name": {
                "name": "Window 2"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.AWNING",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ],
            "roomHint": "Second Bedroom"
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-330035000a47363339343638-28",
            "name": {
                "name": "Blind 1"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.BLINDS",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ],
            "roomHint": "Second Bedroom"
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-330035000a47363339343638-18",
            "name": {
                "name": "Blind 2"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.BLINDS",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ],
            "roomHint": "Second Bedroom"
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-34002c000a47363339343638-15",
            "name": {
                "name": "Blind 1"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.BLINDS",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ],
            "roomHint": "Living Room"
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-34002c000a47363339343638-16",
            "name": {
                "name": "Blind 2"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.BLINDS",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ],
            "roomHint": "Living Room"
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-34002c000a47363339343638-10",
            "name": {
                "name": "Front Door"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.DOOR",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OpenClose"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "HOME-340031000d47363330353437-133",
            "name": {
                "name": "Stove"
            },
            "willReportState": true,
            "deviceInfo": {
                "manufacturer": "XXXX"
            },
            "customData": {
                "device_class": "XXXX",
                "device_id": "XX",
                "property_id": XX
            },
            "type": "action.devices.types.OUTLET",
            "traits": [
                "action.devices.traits.OnOff"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So everything is exactly the same, except that I changed the device type and it started to work.

[image: Google Assistant 2]

Comment: When I try it with those devices, it works just as I expect.

Comment: @NickFelker Okay I updated my answer with some additional troubleshooting. I changed the device type to 'AWNING' and that made it work. What are your thoughts about that?

Comment: I'm not sure why the original issue was happening.

Comment: I mean, the original issue still happens when I switch the device type back to windows. Is this something I'll have to contact Google support directly ? If so how might I go about that.

Comment: I don't know why the issue is happening. Google support may not be able to assist.

Comment: this seems like an issue stemming from Google's back end though and I'd like to actually figure it out. Are you saying there's nothing I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any errors in your project's StackDriver logs corresponding to these request IDs? [developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/develop/error-logging](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/develop/error-logging)
Make sure you select "Google Assistant Action" in the resource filter (for me, by default it was "Cloud Function") to see what Google Assistant is complaining about after the command got executed.